# Shift commands within bash script

Tags: bash

I need a way to execute same command inside "for" loop, e.g. command 1.
Indeed i need this, because command 1 is very long and should be executed similar for deferent variables.

```
if [ $variable = 'all' ]; then  
  for host in "${servers[@]}"; do   
command 1
  done
elif [ $variable != 'all' ]; then
--->go to command 1
fi
```

Comment: You might still receive answers to your question, but it appears that you need to provide more information.

Comment: And the problem is?.. (looks quite ok to me, except for elif branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what functions are for: code re-use

```
do_command1() {
    local host=$1
    command1 "$host" arg ...
}

if [ $variable = 'all' ]; then  
    for host in "${servers[@]}"; do   
        do_command1 "$host"
    done
else 
    do_command1 def_host
fi
```

Comment: Almost this approach used, but i redefined $host in else statement

Answer (score 1):

Create a common array to iterate over, setting *its* value based on `$variable`:

```
if [[ $variable = 'all' ]]; then
    my_arr=( "${servers[@]}" )
else
    # You may need to provide a suitable value for the lone
    # array element here, other than "dummy_host"
    my_arr=( dummy_host )
fi

for host in "${my_arr[@]}"; do
    command 1
done
```